# When it is better to drop variable rather than impute continues or recategorize missing in categorical in predictive modeling?

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, missing-data

Is there any general consensus to when it is better to drop variable rather than impute continues or recategorize missing in categorical in predictive modeling? I mean, maybe there is some kind of percentage of count of missing values in variable or other statistic that shows that it is better to drop that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no magical percentage threshold which decides whether to keep (and impute) or throw away a feature. In most cases it depends on the situation i.e. the feature itself and what you like to predict.

I'd say if you have more than 50% missing values you should very much consider to drop the feature. Consider if it makes sense to impute by mean / median, what is the distribution of that feature, is it really useful if you impute the larger amount of the data? There is a clear trade-off: features with high variance are probably more useful, but also harder to impute.

Comment: What about missing data for categorical variables?

Comment: The same ideas apply.